# Set a property of scope object dynamically in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am writing a generic method to get some data from a service and populate in the dynamic property name passed in the function. the value does gets assigned to the text  box using angular.element assignment but does not gets populated in the model. following is the code.

```
<div class="input-group">
<input class="form-control" id="ImgRollover" name="ImgRollover" ng-model="contentEntity.imgRollover" placeholder="" readonly="readonly" type="text">
<div class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="pickImage('contentEntity.imgRollover')">

    </button>
</div>
```

here is my controller method which internally uses a service which sends back a promise

```
$scope.pickImage = function (attrModel) {
        ImageSelector.selectImage().then(
            function (value) {
                //angular.element("#" + attrModel).val(value);
                $scope[attrModel] = value;
        });
};
```

attrModel is a property name in the scope object contentEntity but the name of the property is known ONLY dynamically via the method parameter.

Comment: ng_model - is it typo? must be ng-model

Comment: no need to set the value using `val()` when it is bound using `ng-model` ( with proper syntax)

Comment: You are selecting an element by id 'contentEntity.imgRollover' which doesn't exist

Comment: @Vladimir sorry, ng_model was a typo. it is ng-model in the code.

Comment: and your problem is?

Comment: @aduch if the ID is same that part works, but the main challenge is to assign the value to the model.

Comment: @Noypi my problem is that the model value does not gets populated

Comment: because you probably pass a string 'contentEntity.imgRollover'.

Comment: try removing the single quotes.

Comment: You cant get object value like this obj['contentEntity.imgRollover'] use obj['contentEntity']['imgRollover'] insted

Comment: @noypi removing single quotes does not help :-(

Comment: should have unless contentEntity is undefined or imgRollover is empty. have you tried logging attrModel.

Comment: @noypi yes, ive tried doing logging and it does have value

Comment: @VladimirGordienko it works like this $scope['contentEntity']['imgRollover'] = value; but the main point is to pass these 2 parts as part of attrModel, so if i try like this attrModel = ['contentEntity']['imgRollover'];
                    $scope[attrModel] = value; it does not works

Comment: so add two params... pickImage('contentEntity', 'imgRollover')

Comment: @VladimirGordienko already did that and it worked beautifully :-) pls post your answer in the answer so that i can mark it as answer :-)

Comment: @Vikram I proposed something else if you ever need to use an unknow n object depth

Comment: @aduch thats indeed much more flexible. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="pickImage('contentEntity', 'imgRollover')"></button>

$scope.pickImage = function (attrModel1, attrModel2) {
        ImageSelector.selectImage().then(function (value) {
                $scope.[attrModel1][attrModel2] = value;
        });
};
```

should work

Answer (score 2):

I know this has already been well answered but I wanted to make a dynamic property creator.
It splits `attrModel` by `'.'` and then edits `$scope` and adds and/or returns each property if it either exists already or not, we preserve the last key outside of the while loop so that the value just has to be appended to it.

```
$scope.pickImage = function (attrModel) {
        ImageSelector.selectImage().then(
            function (value) {
                var parent = $scope,
                    current,
                    attribute,
                    attributes = attrModel.split('.');

                while(attributes.length > 1 &&
                      (attribute = attributes.shift()) &&
                      (current = parent[attribute] || (parent[attribute] = {}))) {

                    parent = current;
                }
                current[attributes[0]] = value;
        });
};
```

Of course, if you want to do it the angular way you'd have to use a service in order to do that, it could look like this

### [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/axelduch/t1525ck5/)

```
angular.module('myApp').service('ObjectWalker', function () {
        var getNodeData = function (object, path) {
            var parent = object,
                current,
                attribute,
                attributes = path.split('.');

            while(attributes.length > 1 &&
                  (attribute = attributes.shift()) &&
                  (current = parent[attribute] || (parent[attribute] = {}))) {

                parent = current;
            }
            return [current, attributes[0]];
        };

        return {
            set: function(object, path, value) {
                var nodeData = getNodeData(object, path);
                nodeData[0][nodeData[1]] = value;
            },
            get: function(object, path) {
                var nodeData = getNodeData(object, path);
                return nodeData[0][nodeData[1]];
            }
        };
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already an answer but, just like to post something for dynamic properties...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var value = 0;
      function mainCtrl($scope) {

        value++;

        $scope.pickImage = function (attrModel) {
            value++;
            alert(attrModel)
            $scope[attrModel] = value;
        };

        $scope.getValue = function(attrModel) {
          return $scope[attrModel];
        }

      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app ng-controller="mainCtrl">

      <input type="text" ng-model="test.obj" />

      <br/>
      <button ng-click="pickImage(test.obj)">test</button>
      <br/>
      display the value afoter button click,
      note there is no single quote
      <br/>
      value: {{ getValue(test.obj) }}


  </body>

</html>
```