# Dynamically updating database (Firebase) with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I couldn't find the answer anywhere. Is there a way to dynamically set the record database names while updating it via `$http` request?

```
$scope.patchSingle = function(key, recordName, recordValue) {

    $http.patch('https://DATABASE_ADDRESS/'+key+'.json', { recordName: recordValue})
    .success(function(result){
        console.log('success');
    })  
    .error(function (result) {
       console.log('error');  
    });
};
```

I just need to make `recordName` variable dynamically set by `ptachSingle` function argument in `$http.patch` request.

Comment: OK, found the answer, just didn`t know how to properly ask this question. Soulution I found is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725081/set-a-property-of-scope-object-dynamically-in-angular-js
what I need is to use [recordName] instead of recordName.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916/creating-object-with-dynamic-keys